# select2 keyboard nevigation not working with closeOnSelect set to false

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When I set `closeOnSelect` option to `true`, I could navigate between options using up and down keys. After the first selection, it did not allow any more keyboard navigation. It only allow to select using mouse and scroll through mouse-wheel.

I am using `select2` version 4.0.0-rc.1
I tried older versions. there it is working fine. But those have some UI issues when used with `bootstrap3`.

Did anyone get solution/workaround to this issue?

thanks

Comment: Any idea if this was fixed in 4.0.0-rc.2?

Comment: @KevinBrown I check 4.0.0-rc.2 version. That issue is not fixed there.